# JAVA Nested Loop Usage

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I have an assignment I am trying to complete using nested for loops, but I cannot seem to figure out how I can do this.

I need to:

**Write a program to simulate tossing a pair of 11-sided dice and determine 
the percentage of times each possible combination of the dice is rolled. 
Ask the user to input how many times the dice will be rolled. 
 Calculate the probability of each combination of dice.**

I am not quite getting how to process the results of the rolls (which I have figured out already), heres where im at in my code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < total_rolls; x++){
      int result = roll(sides); //roll(sides) gets two random ints under 12, then adds them together

    }
```

Comment: So, is there a question? Besides "what do I do next?"

Comment: thats pretty much it, for the first time im stumped on these

Comment: This is really a Statistics Question more then anything else.

Think about it this way. How many ways are there to roll two n-sided die? And how do you determine the probability of a particular result from a set of possible results?

Comment: we generate random numbers for each roll, so its more programming than that im sure

Comment: @user1332495 I believe Abraham's point is that you're don't seem to be even at the point where you know which statistical calculation you need to implement. (I.e. how to build a histogram from a bunch of samples.) Which isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to count the frequencies (number of occurrences) of your dice value combinations.

You can create a matrix of dimension 11x11. Whenever you roll a combination like `6` on dice 1 and `10` on dice two, you increment that cell in the matrix. You can think of this matrix as a histogram.

The simulated probability of a combination is then obtained by reading an entry out of the matrix and dividing it by the `total_rolls`

This could look something like this

```
int[][]histogram = new int[11][11];
for(int x = 0; x < total_rolls; x++){
  int dice1 = roll(sides); //result of dice 1 (1-11)
  int dice2 = roll(sides); //result of dice 2 (1-11)
  histogram[dice1-1][dice2-1]++; //increment the frequency of this event
}

double prob = 1.0*histogram[5][9]/total_rolls; //probability of combination (6,10)
```

Two details to note, arrays in java are 0 indexed. Also division of two integers results in an integer so we make it a division of a double and an integer by multiplying with the double literal 1.0;